# ro1000an nu1000era50 en100o501ng

Tags: code-golf, string, encoding, roman-numerals

In the hovertext of [this xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2637/):

[image: 100he100k out th1s 1nno5at4e str1ng en100o501ng 15e been 500e5e50op1ng! 1t's 6rtua100y perfe100t! ...hang on, what's a "virtuacy"?]

There's an "encoding" based on replacing runs of roman numerals with their sums. To do this:

- Find all runs of at least 1 roman numeral (`IVXLCDM`)
- Replace them with their sums, as numbers

The Roman Numerals are `IVXLCDM`, corresponding respectively to `1, 5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000`. You should match them in either case.

For example, if we take `encoding`, `c` is the roman numeral 100, so it gets replaced with 100, leaving `en100oding`. Then, `di` are both roman numerals, respectively 500 and 1, so it gets replaced with their sum, 501, leaving `en100o501ng`.

Your challenge is to implement this, given a string. This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest wins!

Note: the xkcd implements some more complex rules regarding consecutive characters like `iv`. This can create some ambiguities so I'm going with this simpler version.

### Testcases

```
xkcd -> 10k600
encodingish -> en100o501ng1sh
Hello, World! -> He100o, Wor550!
Potatoes are green -> Potatoes are green
Divide -> 1007e
bacillicidic -> ba904
```

Comment: Do we have to handle either case, or can we assume, eg, all lowercase?

Comment: @Jonah I'm gonna say either case

Comment: based on the same XKCD: [Not-Roman-Numeral Addition](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/249152/not-roman-numeral-addition)

Comment: That's Numberwang!

Comment: Shouldn't xkcd be 10k400 ?

Comment: @vsz read the challenge.

Answer (score 12):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 9 bytes

```
ƛøṘ∨;⁽-ḊṠ
```

[Try it online](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJzIiwiIiwixpvDuOG5mOKIqDvigb0t4biK4bmgIiwiIiwiSGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkISJd) or [run a test suite](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJhaiIsIsabIiwixpvDuOG5mOKIqDvigb0t4biK4bmgIiwi4oiRXCJgID0+IGBqIiwieGtjZFxuZW5jb2Rpbmdpc2hcbkhlbGxvLCBXb3JsZCFcblBvdGF0b2VzIGFyZSBncmVlblxuRGl2aWRlXG5iYWNpbGxpY2lkaWMiXQ==).

```
ƛøṘ∨;⁽-ḊṠ
ƛ          # Map, and for each character:
 øṘ        #  Convert from roman numeral to a number, or 0 if invalid
   ∨       #  Logical OR with the character: if it's 0, then use the character instead
    ;      # Close map
       Ḋ   # Group results where the same result appears consecutively...
     ⁽-    # ...with subtracting it by itself. Subtracting a number by itself is 0,
           # but subtracting a string by itself is "". These are two different values, so it works as a type check.
        Ṡ  # Sum each. Summing a list of characters will turn it into a string, but lists of numbers will simply sum.
           # The s flag joins the list together into a string before outputting.
```

Comment: Wow this is clever.

Answer (score 4):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `grouping.extras math.unicode roman`, <s>100</s> 99 bytes

```factor
[ 1 group [ [ roman> ] try ] map [ real? ] group-by values [ [ Σ >dec ] try ] map flatten concat ]
```

Needs modern Factor for [>dec](https://docs.factorcode.org/content/word-__gt__dec,math.parser.html). Here's a version that runs on TIO for 3 more bytes, though: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZJRb9QwDMff@yl8fWa9duJuu00aL5MYEkKIgXiYeHATt42ai0uSjqsQn4bvw1e6Oa00boK0al3793dcxw2qyP745f7dh7dX0HoeB@PaZ6OgQ/QYAENgFSDQ95GcogCe9@hgj7EDTfXYtuShJ@/IwuApxmnwxsVkB5K34b/aQhMNs7QYnVGsCa6z7GcGsvJDr3QOL9cKzm6gKvttWS6QpGEt1ZnQ5S8gclVZ8qasXFuFboHvyFp@BV/ZW73KT@A7SvAc2WzK1UJ/5IiR5QfRk3SByOUL/W9gEdyaR6Mp/1/B5QUtTI3KWGuU0Ublp0yNu/J19is7PkC19Bwe5JqbewPfIPpJnntMbk9o38jXjJ3VEzyiHaWeJPjz@7nTp6LGYozkQLFTKKFjcjoLBShL6LNsBfdE0MU4hKv1Oh1Fy7YpQkTV00F16FoqFO/XuD4/Ly8vt@vdxa7aQsMefnQTCOg0ep3Ot5MxqaUtkAamIw1SouSgIRqWSaEQsE3tc3qWxs4EkJt7nAop5PP769tPknBsmuSexyclGaOgBDzGQcwkkB14AG5mv8aIMNcL2EQZwuRsRqfmXQVXaC3p4vgE)

##### How?

This answer relies on `try` in order to process heterogeneous arrays relatively succinctly, as `roman>` blows up on non- roman numbers and `sum` blows up on arrays of strings.

```
                          ! "encodingish"
1 group                   ! { "e" "n" "c" "o" "d" "i" "n" "g" "i" "s" "h" }
[ [ roman> ] try ] map    ! { "e" "n" 100 "o" 500 1 "n" "g" 1 "s" "h" }
[ real? ] group-by values ! { V{ "e" "n" } V{ 100 } V{ "o" } V{ 500 1 } V{ "n" "g" } V{ 1 } V{ "s" "h" } }
[ [ Σ >dec ] try ] map    ! { V{ "e" "n" } "100" V{ "o" } "501" V{ "n" "g" } "1" V{ "s" "h" } }
flatten                   ! { "e" "n" "100" "o" "501" "n" "g" "1" "s" "h" }
concat                    ! "en100o501ng1sh"
```

Comment: "Language: Factor + the kitchen sink". This is why I love Factor. What other language randomly comes with a "to Roman" function built-in in some standard library somewhere?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo A lot of golfing languages do. But they include it because they anticipate Roman numerals in golf questions. I think Factor has it because there is a small, but enthusiastic group of people who like writing stuff in Factor. Incidentally, the [roman vocabulary](https://github.com/factor/factor/blob/master/basis/roman/roman.factor) is touted as being a good introductory example of Factor code, as it is well-written and includes many language features such as metaprogramming.

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 91 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.replace(/[ivxlcdm]+/gi,s=>Buffer(s).map(c=>t-=~[9,4,,99,499,49,999][c%32%24%7],t=0)|t)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY@xboMwEIb3PoVjCQlUB0wKjRjIUHXI2K0DYnDsg1zj2Mh2UYaqr07TdEloTrrTL/3fN9yHGIWXDoewNFbB1NWTrzc@dTBoISHOGhxPWqpj@5j1yM7dy2fXgYt9kh7FEMt6E5b1d1OxgrHqfC97TlXbyOhpFa2KaN2yUPPkKySTtMZbDam2fdzF9HSQipKbSRKSZSTnh2fOH2Y4GGkVmh79nt7gYHLObclz0@d@P9e2oLVl5N06rRb0StvCr3ZpypIv5t6bDSJY8EQ4IL0DMPTP@1/M1VccUQG99xhfw5zeCYlao0SFkl7TO1HxYvoB)

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 146 bytes

```
\(s){`!`=is.na
T=tapply
r=as.roman(t<-el(strsplit(s,"")))
a=T(r,i<-rep(seq(a=x<-rle(!r)$l),x),sum)
a[!a]<-T(t,i,g<-\(x)Reduce(paste0,x))[!a]
g(a)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=Zc_PSsNAEAbwe54iiR5mYVM2YP0DiScPPYoEPFih02SaLt3uxt2tRMSX8OolCr6O976NiQ0ieBq--X6Hmbd3232s8s-dXyXn-9c5OPa8iBa5dBONQZF7bBr1FNgc3cSaLWrwWUIKnLeuUdKD43HMGAswL8BymSWWGnD0AJi3fVAEkWXHivGWcbfb9vAuwvssKcBzyessmUPLbqjalQQNOk-il2wwQQ3IXsbLvlYQky5NJXUds6BP7aasYnYUJpdhKjanQgR_iHTrsSOdCmGmItV16taDmZFShoe3xqoqGtWMBvWznE5FNLBr49EbciFaCmtLpEf7vxj4lXyUFf0eJM5o2C6xlErJUlayHLslXoiTw1ddd5jf)

Definitely not the best tool for the job, despite built-in `roman` numerals.

#### Explanation outline:

1. Split string to characters (stored in `t`; this part could be omitted if we took input as a vector of characters).
2. Convert to type `roman` - successful for Roman digits, otherwise `NA` (stored in `r`).
3. Build index `i` for spitting on consecutive runs of `NA`s or not `NA`s.
4. Tapply (`split`+`sapply`) sum on Roman numerals.
5. Fill `NA`s with chunks from original string.
6. Collapse vector to one string.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ret1na 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 45 bytes

```
i(`m
dd
d
5$*c
c
ll
l
5$*x
x
vv
v
5$*i
i+
$.&
```

[Try 1t on51ne!](https://tio.run/##FcYxCgIxEAXQ/p8iwiKiy3bewMLSztY4M6wfxwSyIeT2kX3VK1aZ4hg8vX5QheI6nQUCd/j@jo7W0PYTvGBajmP0rygsSVamldsHd3PPc3jm4nrAI9dYs20hFgtrMUu4sVEN7yh0p1Apfw) 51nk 1n150u500es test 100ases. E10p50anat1on:

```
i(`
```

Run the who50e s100r1pt 100ase-1nsens1t6e50y.

```
m
dd
```

1000 = 2 * 500.

```
d
5$*c
```

500 = 5 * 100.

```
c
ll
```

100 = 2 * 50.

```
l
5$*x
```

50 = 5 * 10.

```
x
vv
```

10 = 2 * 5.

```
v
5$*i
```

5 = 5 * 1.

```
i+
$.&
```

100on5ert to 500e1101a50.

Comment: It took me a while to figure out `500e1101a50` :P

Comment: @emanresuA Too much decimal?

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 21 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
.γu.vd}εDSu.v©àdi®O]J
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f79zmUr2ylNpzW12CgYxDKw8vSMk8tM4/1uv//4rs5BTHJAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfaXSf71zm0v1ylJqz211CQYyDq08vCAl89A6/1iv/0p6YTr/o5UqspNTlHSUUvOS81My89IzizOAPI/UnJx8HYXw/KKcFEUgPyC/JLEkP7VYIbEoVSG9KDU1DyjoklmWmZIKZCQlJmfm5GQmZ6ZkJgO5IBMdk5RiAQ).

Or alternatively, with I/O as character array:

```
u.vøεΣa}н}.γd}ε¤diO]S
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@/VK/s8I5zW88tTqy9sLdW79zmlNpzWw8tScn0jw3@/z9aqUJJRykbiJOBOAWIHYE4SSkWAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWWwi9L/Ur2ywzvObT23OLH2wt5avXObU2rPbT20JCXTPzb4v5JemJfO/2iliuzkFCUdpdS85PyUzLz0zOIMIM8jNScnX0chPL8oJ0URyA/IL0ksyU8tVkgsSlVIL0pNzQMKumSWZaakAhlJicmZOTmZyZkpmclALshExySlWAA).

Can definitely be golfed a bit. But despite having a Roman Number builtin, the functionality of some builtins are nowhere near as versatile as the Vyxal answer.. Why you might ask?

1. The Roman Number builtin only works on uppercase letters (probably a bug..), so preserving the casing costs quite a few bytes.
2. Sum given an error on letters in the new 05AB1E version, so explicit checks before summing are unfortunately necessary.

**Explanation:**

```python
.γ             # Adjacent group by the (implicit) input-string:
  u            #  Convert to uppercase
   .v          #  Convert from letter to Roman Number
     d         #  Check if this is a (non-negative) integer
 }ε            # After the adjacent group-by: map over each group:
   D           #  Duplicate the current group
    S          #  Convert it to a list of characters
     u         #  Uppercase each
      .v       #  Convert it to a Roman Number
               #  (it will remain an uppercase character if invalid)
        ©      #  Store this list in variable `®` (without popping)
         àdi   #  If this list contains an integer:
            ®O #   Push and sum list `®`
  ]            # Close the if-statement and map
   J           # Join everything together to a single string
               # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

```python
u              # Uppercase each character in the (implicit) input-list
 .v            # Convert each to a Roman Number
               # (it will remain an uppercase character if invalid)
   ø           # Pair each with the characters of (implicit) input-list
    ε          # Map over each pair:
     Σ         #  (Stable) sort the pair by:
      a        #   Check if it's a letter (0 if number; 1 if letter)
     }н        #  After the sort-by: pop and push the first character
    }.γ        # After the map: adjacent group by:
       d       #  Is it a (non-negative) integer
      }ε       # After the adjacent group-by: map over each group:
        ¤      #  Push the first item (without popping the group list)
         di    #  If it's a (non-negative) integer:
           O   #   Sum the group together
       ]       # Close the if-statement and map
        S      # Convert the numbers and remaining groups to a flattened list
               # of characters
               # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 52 bytes

```
≔⁰θＦ⊞Ｏ⪪Ｓ¹ω«≔⌕⪪IVXLCDM¹↥ιη¿⊕η≧⁺×Ｘχ÷η²⊕×⁴﹪η²θ«⁺∨θωι≔⁰θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZBNawMhEIbP7q@wOY1goSm99VQSShe6ZGn6dZV1sgpGjbrJoeS3W2X30B7mIDw@874zKBEGJ0zOTzHq0cIdpyf22BxcoNBPUe08BpFcgL03OkFr/ZT2KWg7AuN0XebCGP1pyPL/WVu5sKv28/t1s@1WM/fhi2oQEUGz8lRlC9EHWpRDwCPahBJUcXXCz643PaoEvZkip@/6iBF6d8EA65KxtWmrz1oiKE7vq@@vZqYfOO2cnIxbmErVbgRNxBqZ9KXHvAF2AU61C6clXWHI/3uQa3PN@QWNcZx@uWDkTZNvz@YX) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔⁰θ
```

Start with a running total of `0`.

```
Ｆ⊞Ｏ⪪Ｓ¹ω«
```

Loop over the input characters, but include a trailing empty string.

```
≔⌕⪪IVXLCDM¹↥ιη
```

Get the index of the uppercase character in the list of Roman numerals.

```
¿⊕η
```

If this is a Roman numeral, then...

```
≧⁺×Ｘχ÷η²⊕×⁴﹪η²θ«
```

... use the index to convert it to decimal and add it to the running total, otherwise:

```
⁺∨θωι
```

Prefix the running total, if any, to the character before printing it.

```
≔⁰θ
```

Clear the running total.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>130</s> <s>122</s> 117 bytes

*-8 bytes by porting Arnauld's formula*

*-5 bytes thanks to movatica*

```python
lambda s:re.sub('[ivxlcdm]+',lambda M:str(sum(1+[9,4,0,99,499,49,999][ord(i)%32%24%7]for i in M[0])),s,0,2)
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY49a8MwEIZ3/wrVYCIRUVIn0NqQrUOXQLcOroezJCdH9WFOinF/veuIDsc973McvNNvugV/fJtoHc/fqwU3aGCxJfMc7wPfdTgvVmnX73fy/3hpYyIe746/7LtGnuRBNtvKs1HTd4E0R1Ed66o@Va/9GIghQ88u3aEXQsbtoxYFuilQYmTWZGKK565g5fKjdCk3MF4Fjf6K8Zbzh7E2SPYVyOqnbD5DghRMZECGXckYn/U7zqhNxgEUWosKNaosEGZYwIICDa4s@uLRLD2a5QZtwSZCn/jIkxDrHw)

Matches runs of roman numerals and replaces them with their sum. The `2` at the end is equivalent to `re.IGNORECASE`.

Comment: `M[0]` instead of `M.group()` for 117 bytes

Comment: @movatica Nice! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>150</s> <s>159</s> <s>152</s> <s>137</s> <s>133</s> 126 bytes

- +9 to handle either case
- -7 thanks to emanresu A
- -22 thanks to ceilingcat
- -4 thanks to Neil

Processes a string, looking for Roman numerals. If it finds one, the value is added to the total consecutive run. Once a non-numeral is found, the total is printed if it is greater than zero (and the total is reset), then the non-numeral is printed. Finally, the total is printed if the end of string is encountered in case the final character was a Roman numeral.

```c
char*n="ivxlcdm",*d;t;f(char*s){for(t=0;t=!(d=index(n,*s|32))?t&&printf("%d",t),*s&&!putchar(*s):t+L"\1\5\n2dǴϨ"[d-n],*s++;);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU/LTsMwELznK7ZGRHbiIijigkk5UCQqKm48pLaHYDupJdeu4m1BKvkfPoB/4MgfEdxWQtrDzszu7I7s11J2nVyUTeYKYjbvVqol4ZkSKCq65wPbVr6hWJwKLHpUFcYp/U4dz8LH@YCxa0zTVWMcVpQcK8KRRSVNe6s17vZpNLjEfEJmZ7OLmRuo76@fTzJVfTePc3kumGi7I@OkXSsNVwGV8SeLYZJER1iWxtGNN4rBNgHY@UEWpvNiS17ub0aEE@2kV8bVJiwiutPWeg7PvrGqF/HKY4leBygbDXWjtYvkaPw0Ht3G5rWUxlojjTKS8IfHyaTlkGUo4qlYh9RBQGQgpgmUEHZ4BOA/cYBiCCTuIRN7paIZ5vketEnb/crKlnXo@m9/)

Comment: You can save 7 bytes by [or with 32](https://tio.run/##RU9Nb8IwDL33V5hsoDYNEx/isqzsMJCGhnbbh4Q4dE5aIoUENaFDYv3rdAGkTbJsP9tPfg/7JWLb4iavqMmIqg8axZYwKhjyerXOjkM2YcMBmwxCPpdQ5@OGeV7EF5ZLjoWtYp8NOGbUpSkXmTJCHmLD8Gc8ShKfiUef1ivRN@v7zq5Sxhcx6Yru6BZJ2vF0xDzDhPte739JmE94094og3ovJDw4L5S920yjKJzANlcmrq0SCRwjgLMSoO6sl3y@PM0II9KgFcqUym0CepZaWwYfttKiE/DO@txb6SCvJJSVlCYMZ4v3xWwemq8cldYKlVBI2OvbctkwoNTz8CrE1a/jECaw23sXE5JchQD8WXCQTYEEXjBy2RQx9Wl6AU3UtCcsdF66tv/9Cw) and loweracse.

Comment: [135 bytes](https://tio.run/##PU9LTsMwEN3nFIMRkZ24CIrYYFwWFImKih0fqe0i2E5iybWr2P1IIffhANyBJTciuEVCmsX76M28EYNKiL4XddFkliO92Rkhl4hmkgoWWIkPjidt4GdMulbwzOc5CxxLrq1UO2ypeL8YEnIT8iman88v53Yovz6/P9BMDuziCoc0XTXahhKjE4loIFSk6dFqHfarsSCEddtaGxUh6/pjbYVZSwXXPkjtTutRksQwLAtt8cZpSaBNAPZZyPxswVv0@nA7RhQpK5zUttK@juxeGeMovLjGyKPIVy4UwSkPRaOgapSyURxPnifjuwjeCqGN0UJLLRB9fJpOOwpZFlg8Fad0DQ7cM4gKxOYeI0T@igD8P@eBjwDFXCDs4JQ4C3l@IF3S9T@iNEXl@8H2Fw "C (gcc) – Try It Online") but feels like it should be shorter.