# Not-Roman-Numeral Addition

Tags: code-golf, math, number, roman-numerals

Write the shortest program or function that mimics the addition in this [XKCD strip](https://xkcd.com/2637/):

[image]

### Input

Two positive decimal integers containing only the digits `150`.

### Output

The positive decimal integer result of adding the two inputs together in the manner shown above. This output should also only have the digits `150`.

### Specification

#### Input and Output

Input and output are numbers only containing digits `150`.

#### Roman Numerals

This challenge will use [Standard Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals#Standard_form) numerals:

|  | Thousands | Hundreds | Tens | Units |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | M | C | X | I |
| 2 | MM | CC | XX | II |
| 3 | MMM | CCC | XXX | III |
| 4 | MMMM | CD | XL | IV |
| 5 | MMMMM | D | L | V |
| 6 | MMMMMM | DC | LX | VI |
| 7 | MMMMMMM | DCC | LXX | VII |
| 8 | MMMMMMMM | DCCC | LXXX | VIII |
| 9 | MMMMMMMMM | CM | XC | IX |

Note the subtractive notation on multiples of `40` and `90`, and additive notation on multiples of `1000`.

### Worked Example

Consider a test case below, `1010111 + 101051 = 1050110 (23 + 26 = 49)`.

Convert the inputs to Roman numerals, then to Arabic numerals:

```
1010111 => XXIII => 23
101051  => XXVI  => 26
```

Perform the addition:

```
23 + 26 => 49
```

Convert the output back to Roman numerals, then for each Roman numeral substitute its Arabic numeral value:

```
49 => XLIX => 10 50 1 10 => 1050110
```

### Test Cases

```
A + B = C (explanation)
=========
1 + 1 = 11 (1 + 1 = 2)
11 + 11 = 15 (2 + 2 = 4 == IV)
15 + 5 = 110 (4 + 5 = 9 == IX)
101010 + 1 = 1010101 (30 + 1 = 31)
1010 + 111 = 1010111 (20 + 3 = 23)
1010 + 15 = 101015 (20 + 4 = 24)
1010 + 5 = 10105 (20 + 5 = 25)
1010111 + 101051 = 1050110 (23 + 26 = 49)
101015 + 51 = 101010 (24 + 6 = 30)
1010015 + 15 = 101005111 (94 + 4 = 98)
100010010010101015 + 1000100010010010010505 = 100010001000500501010110 (1234 + 2345 = 3579)
100010010010101015 + 1000100010001000100010001000100050010010050105 = 100010001000100010001000100010001000100100010100110 (1234 + 8765 = 9999)
```

### Other Notes

As seen in the comic, Randall is doing a simple substitution of Roman numerals with their decimal equivalents:

- `I => 1`
- `V => 5`
- `X => 10`

Presumably, this will be extended for all Roman numerals (up to 1000):

- `L => 50`
- `C => 100`
- `D => 500`
- `M => 1000`

For more information, see the [ExplainXKCD wiki page](https://explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/2637:_Roman_Numerals).

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins!

Comment: Based on the same XKCD: [ro1000an nu1000era50 en100o501ng](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/249107/ro1000an-nu1000era50-en100o501ng)

Comment: @Arnauld, Steffan yeah that testcase had two extra zeroes, fixed now

Comment: @Arnauld thanks for letting me know, these test case issues should've been caught in sandbox but weren't somehow?

Comment: The last test case is wrong too. `100010001000100010001000100010001010010050105` is `MMMMMMMMXCCLXV`, but it should be `MMMMMMMMDCCLXV` (`1000100010001000100010001000100050010010050105`).

Comment: May we take the string sum as input instead of 2 separate arguments? (e.g. `"1010+15"`)

Comment: @Arnauld yes, as long as it is one of the [default io methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods)

Comment: Isn't there an error in `1010015 + 15 = 501005111`? Unless I misunderstand something, it should be `101005111`

Comment: @CommandMaster oops that is a mistake, thanks for catching it

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 21 bytes

```
ƛ`.0*`Ẏ⌊øṘṅøṘ;∑øṘvøṘṅ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLGm2AuMCpg4bqO4oyKw7jhuZjhuYXDuOG5mDviiJHDuOG5mHbDuOG5mOG5hSIsIiIsIltcIjEwMTAxMTFcIiwgXCIxMDEwNTFcIl0iXQ==)

### How?

```
ƛ`.0*`Ẏ⌊øṘṅøṘ;∑øṘvøṘṅ
ƛ                      # Map, and for both strings:
 `.0*`Ẏ                #  Get all regex matches ".0*"
       ⌊               #  Convert each to integers
        øṘ             #  Convert each to their roman numeral
          ṅ            #  Join together to a single string
           øṘ          #  Convert from roman numeral to number
             ;         # Close map
              ∑        # Sum
               øṘ      # Convert to roman numeral
                 vøṘ   # Convert each character from roman numeral to number
                    ṅ  # Join together to a string
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org) + `roman`, <s>117</s> 114 bytes

```factor
[ [ R/ .0*/ all-matching-subseqs [ dec> >roman ] f map-as concat ] bi@
roman+ 1 group [ roman> >dec ] map-concat ]
```

Needs modern Factor for [>dec](https://docs.factorcode.org/content/word-__gt__dec,math.parser.html), but here's a version that works on ATO for 3 more bytes:

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=rZS_TsMwEMYXpj7FsYKSOoMlBCJiQywMIKaqg2ucNKJNUttRi6o-CUsX2HgF3gOehrOdP0pBFapxHEW5-H53-Zx8L28J47qQ26-jj4f7m9vrc5DFnOUwZ3oalkwqIaGUQolcgxKLSuRcKHgSMhczSGVRlVmemhVaP5cyw1VMqYIrWCy79aFYackUSJGKVQkXg8F6ADgWyzVEeGzAbxzDJURRh4zM9INaJO2QFKhvm65L0jGJOfxe3zItJ-pxsdD_cKNdrp8MLZf2sZ7iNtg-1WhgowdK4aiU_Ng0_Bh81O02rcVSgnfEkA8X2GBrDu3vmw3aWbdfh9qwEYnsK-xabpNwtdHFakz-WOjXkzYZhmYa2C20P9Gm2R42r5VOgrPPagQjuBtCSE6GwGazAI2MT9GjAlVN0JAUPn4UPIbY-dwYEvS6MkB34kXOmcbIJLtyLniKP6f1OEyygbj1wrHNalJc8ffEmV-MjyB0se3WXb8B)

-3 bytes thanks to @Steffan

Comment: You can use `.0*` instead of `[15]0*`

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 204 bytes

Expects `(a)(b)`, where both arguments are strings.

```javascript
a=>b=>(h=(n,k)=>n?h(n/10|0,k+0)+[k%8?[,k,d=k+k,d+k,k+(x=k*5),x,x+k,x+d,x+d+k,d+0][n%10]:k.repeat(n)]:'')((g=s=>s.replace(p=/.0*/g,s=>s-p?(t+=s<p?n:s-n,p=s<p?n=+s:0/(n=0)):n+=p=+s,t=n=0)&&t+n)(a)+g(b),'1')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZTfbpswFMbv9xRWpTbHtROOAbcB7STXe4FpUpQLmtB0I3JQQVMu9u6ZjyFR1dJKGzWywebP7/j7PvGr@F00m@efdTt1h215eqRTQYsHWsATgdOVpIVbPoGLDP5BXSmUalVdz5crXektVcqPvlcKjlTdWqmP@ujnR7XlHu7ieuWuDa7zavZc1mXRgpPrfDKRADtqaNHw8r7YlFBTNMPbaKd5dVovoVXUfK2XLm@mTtfdNakmxwgcoZS5U1T7Bd0Sz29uWuUkFFLt4EHqiZnI0@bgmsO@nO0PO3iEK3MlwyDFyBZFwhgBRihhBIlYfnlN6lDjWUyyAmJPij0pFUTi2/e3PMs8O35rYWcoIPVA64FZAP54C0Q@PkFPBoZveT0T7AVNzCCw0/STgGxgzMCEHUzeB45V9Qy0PS9lXvoub7SJPe@MYxdjO2xgH1N@@r9VDTiLITVxwjm946Bmw8Qup@MsvETGAzmnzEtwkNcDx3nY87xGnJks7T3M5gNIDFDEPtMdvVu93GG58eOKAvLyln@cFQ6O@U2bOOEa/MjeJvY@@/dCBrs9v8SwrsBXhXzQuxNfvKhxfn8X/iK@ydNf)

#### Parsing the input strings

```javascript
g = s =>                    // s = input string
s.replace(                  // search in s:
  p = /.0*/g,               //   each non-zero digit followed by some 0's
  s =>                      //   given this substring s:
  s - p ?                   //     if s is not equal to the previous match:
    (                       //
      t +=                  //       add to t:
        s < p ? n           //         either n if s < p
              : s - n,      //         or s - n otherwise (e.g. 1 10 -> 9)
      p =                   //       set p to:
        s < p ? n = +s      //         s (also loaded in n) if s < p
              : 0 / (n = 0) //         or NaN otherwise (and set n to 0)
    )                       //
  :                         //     else:
    n +=                    //       add s to the accumulator n
      p = +s,               //       and copy s in p
  t = n = 0                 //   start with t = n = 0
)                           // end of replace()
&& t + n                    // return the sum of t and the accumulator
```

#### Formatting the output

```javascript
h = (n, k) =>               // n = number to convert, k = current prefix
n ?                         // if n is not equal to 0:
  h(                        //   do a recursive call with:
    n / 10 | 0,             //     floor(n / 10)
    k + 0                   //     a '0' appended to k
  ) +                       //   end of recursive call
  [                         //   append:
    k % 8 ?                 //     if k is not equal to '1000':
      [ ,                   //       0 : nothing
        k,                  //       1 : k           --> e.g. '10'
        d = k + k,          //       2 : k+k         --> '1010'
        d + k,              //       3 : k+k+k       --> '101010'
        k + (x = k * 5),    //       4 : k+(5*k)     --> '1050'
        x,                  //       5 : 5*k         --> '50'
        x + k,              //       6 : (5*k)+k     --> '5010'
        x + d,              //       7 : (5*k)+k+k   --> '501010'
        x + d + k,          //       8 : (5*k)+k+k+k --> '50101010'
        d + 0               //       9 : k+k+0       --> '10100'
      ][n % 10]             //       select the correct entry
    :                       //     else:
      k.repeat(n)           //       just repeat '1000' n times
  ]                         //
:                           // else:
  ''                        //   stop the recursion
```

Comment: [157 bytes](https://tio.run/##rZTfasIwFMbv9xRhICYm2pO2UStEr/cCYyBeiFbdKm2xZfTCd3fnxCpDO2HrUtI/SdPfyfd99GP5uSxWh/e87KfZOj5t7KmwU15aUMXgEOf75SrmufUG0PO2CqdKaYupzGdFP@/nE5wqxBGE2lmeqkTYaTrb8dTTcASVSBBynnTGs7lK1NomEs/YE8krm/SMUJWq8LmSa@puFhbztKNhMUmIHi9LnorFpNsVvFRd3RWnVZYW2T4e7LMt3/BnLfWzEKxl8zymNeOaSaaZZb54usUgpz2IMIZxHzE@YkJmLXt5vYcZadpvyu0JGA@RZpAWOdrbPQ3oaCsj0dyHUMYAah0D3UhDKf@JRqb5RAvIteAHWlsxLzRTw0KChc2w1sbVsAuLnPNNs2kUSnr1z2I6lgEXEz@gVA4pllEzDlPZzrZrRpBGqSRYAI0worXzrYahOhSSKKx9i8YNPHBEgDrBiD4PXYdJZXhcjuNdV@HrJKxzCber/YAKwDP5GZhR9MsqGru5rCDSubqbKh7084VuvhU4Hg3drwKbOH0B)

Comment: @tsh That's a really neat idea. I'll update my answer later when/if the OP confirms that it's a valid input format.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>24</s> <s>23</s> 20 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
εDSĀÅ¡J.XJ.v}O.XS.vJ
```

-3 bytes thanks to @CommandMaster

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3FaX4CMNh1sPLfTSi/DSK6v114sI1ivz@v8/2tDAwMAQisDQVEcBKgYXByJTA9NYAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/c1tdgo80HG49tNBLL8JLr6zWXy8iWK/M67/O/@hoQx3DWJ1oQyAFpk11TEGUARBCJIAsoBSCCZNGqAPpBdKmMDUgM2BsEAeqxQDMBSGoIqgQXBhkhgFhtVixKUyHKciU2FgA).

**Original <s>24</s> 23 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) answer:**

```
X3FD5*x}r)D.X:.vO.XS.vJ
```

ASCII only. :)

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/wtjNxVSrorZI00UvwkqvzF8vIlivzOv//2hDAyA0NNQB0aaGsQA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKS/f8IYzcXU62K2iLNymIXvQgrvTJ/vYhgvTKv/zr/o6MNdQxjdaINgRSYNtUxBVEGQAiRALKAUggmTBqhDqQXSJvC1IDMgLFBHKgWAzAXhKCKoEJwYZAZBoTVYsWmMB2mIFNiYwE).

**Explanation:**

```python
ε            # Map over both integers in the (implicit) input-pair:
 D           #  Duplicate the current integer
  S          #  Convert the copy to a list of digits
   Ā         #  Check for each digit that it's NOT 0 (0 if 0; 1 otherwise)
    Å¡       #  Split the number on the truthy (==1) values
      J      #  Join each inner list together
       .X    #  Convert each from an integer to a Roman Numeral
         J   #  Join it together to a single string
          .v # Convert it from a Roman Numeral to an integer
}O           # After the map: sum the two integers together
  .X         # Convert this sum back to a Roman Numeral
    S        # Convert it to a list of characters
     .v      # Convert each character from a Roman Numeral back to an integer
       J     # Join them together
             # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

```python
X3FD5*x}r)   # Push list [1000,500,100,50,10,5,1]:
X            #  Push 1
 3F          #  Loop 3 times:
   D         #   Duplicate the current value
    5*       #   Multiply the copy by 5
      x      #   Double it (without popping)
       }r    #  After the loop: reverse all values on the stack
         )   #  Then wrap the entire stack into a list
D            # Duplicate this list
 .X          # Convert each to a Roman Numeral: ["M","C","D","L","T","V","I"]
   :         # Replace all integers to these characters in the (implicit) input-pair
.v           # Convert both strings from Roman Numerals to integers
  O.XS.vJ    # Same as above
```

Comment: You can split on non-zero digits instead of creating the list of all values, for a -3: `εD€ĀÅ¡J.XJ.v}O.XS.vJ` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3FaXR01rjjQcbj200EsvwkuvrNZfLyJYr8zr//9oQwMDA0MoAkNTHQWoGFwciEwNTGMB "05AB1E – Try It Online") (although you lose the ASCII-onlyness)